# Plural of "is" — "ises" or "isses"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, american-english, orthography

If I had many *is* words, how would I refer to them in the form of a plural? Could I use *ises* or *isses*? Example:

> You use entirely too many isses in your sentences.

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence?

Comment: Well, I'm writing a function for a program. So, it's not really a sentence, but I would like it to flow more English like. I thought `ises` was clever but wasn't sure on the spelling.

Comment: OK, updated my original question.

Comment: It probably won't translate well to your programming context, but in that sentence, I'd be tempted to quote "is": *You use entirely too many "is"es in your sentences.*

Comment: That works. It won't work perfectly, but it is close enough. Thanks!

Comment: You might also consider {identities(...)} or {natures(...)}

Comment: or too many instances of "is".

Comment: Naming variables, functions, classes is expressly off-topic, because as far as both stupid machines and smart human readers (of which, let's be honest for a moment, there will probably be exactly *zero*) are concerned, you can name that function absolutely anything you like. `Ises` is exactly as correct as `Susan51`. So I have removed that bit. The rest of the question is on-topic, though frankly very straightforward (and might consequently still get closed as general reference).

Comment: _Isses_ would be pronounced to rhyme with _hisses_, with an /s/ instead of the proper /z/. If I had to write it (and I would normally avoid it), I'd spell it _is's_.

Comment: @DanBron If the statement is about the specific word "is", it wouldn't make sense to replace it with synonyms. The nature of the complaint could be that the sentence is too repetitious, because it doesn't use synonyms.

Comment: @Barmar, the question has since been edited, but for a period it contained a code snippet along the lines of "function isses(isNumber, isString)". In that context, I was suggesting alternative names for the function. That aside, I agree with you: if someone were complaining about overuse of "is", he would need to pluralize it somehow, not use a synonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to say it's not grammatically possible, but I wouldn't try to pluralize that word. Instead say something like "There are entirely too many instances of the word is".